# How to pass string with special characters to shell command in a script?

Tags: bash, text-processing

I'm writing a small script that will help me debug some permission problems.  I am passing the parent folder I wish to examine and am able to specify any sub-folders which I want to ignore.

I'm having a problem passing the constructed parameter string to `find` because some parts of it (the are being escaped.  I can't seem to figure out how to provide the wildcard into the command in such a way that `find` accepts it properly.  With the wildcard in place, that portion of the path string is qualified using single quotes that are escaped using `'\''` and are confusing me (as I can't figure out how to control the transformation) and `find` (which is essentially ignoring my excludes)

I've been reading all about single and double quotes as well as escaping characters, but I haven't found an example similar to mine.

```
#!/bin/bash -f
# output permissions and ownership with path relative to specified parent.

Usage="$0 <parent path> <excluded child folder> ...."

if [ $# -lt 1 ]
then
    (>&2 echo -e $Usage)
    exit 1
else 
    parent=$1
    shift
    if [ $# -gt 0 ]
    then
        excludes=" ("
        for folder in $@
        do
            thisLine=" ! -path $parent$folder ! -path '$parent$folder/*'"    <=== the '*' wildcard is causing the problem I think.
            excludes=$excludes$thisLine
        done
        excludes=$excludes" )"
    fi
    (>&2 echo "=> find $parent $excludes -ls | awk '{print "'$3"|"$5"|"$6"|"$11}'"'")
    (>&2 echo )
set -vx
    find $parent $excludes -ls | awk '{print $3"|"$5"|"$6"|"$11}'
fi
```

The branch of the tree that I'm working with is `/home/user/catkin_ws/src/clfsm` which has three sub-folders, two of which I wish to exclude; `cmake` & `include`.  The output below is in two parts:  Top is the current output, which does not filter the folders I wish to exclude.  The bottom part is correct, using the echoed command line from my code above.

The command to call the above script is:
`~/myScripts/show_permissions.sh /media/nap/U14041/home/nap/catkin_ws/src/clfsm /cmake /include`. Note that Stephen's solution requires that the sub-folders to be excluded be specified without a leading `/`.

```
user@rMBP-Ubuntu:[12:29]:/home/user/catkin_ws/src/clfsm$ ~/myScripts/show_permissions.sh /home/user/catkin_ws/src/clfsm /cmake /include
=> find /home/user/catkin_ws/src/clfsm  ( ! -path /home/user/catkin_ws/src/clfsm/cmake ! -path '/home/user/catkin_ws/src/clfsm/cmake/*' ! -path /home/user/catkin_ws/src/clfsm/include ! -path '/home/user/catkin_ws/src/clfsm/include/*' ) -ls | awk '{print $3"|"$5"|"$6"|"$11}'

++ find /home/user/catkin_ws/src/clfsm '(' '!' -path /home/user/catkin_ws/src/clfsm/cmake '!' -path ''\''/home/user/catkin_ws/src/clfsm/cmake/*'\''' '!' -path /home/user/catkin_ws/src/clfsm/include '!' -path ''\''/home/user/catkin_ws/src/clfsm/include/*'\''' ')' -ls
++ awk '{print $3"|"$5"|"$6"|"$11}'
drwxrwxr-x|user|user|/home/user/catkin_ws/src/clfsm
-rw-rw-r--|user|user|/home/user/catkin_ws/src/clfsm/clfsm.layout
drwxrwxr-x|user|user|/home/user/catkin_ws/src/clfsm/src
-rw-rw-r--|user|user|/home/user/catkin_ws/src/clfsm/src/clfsm_visitorsupport.cc
-rw-rw-r--|user|user|/home/user/catkin_ws/src/clfsm/src/clfsm_machine.cc
-rw-rw-r--|user|user|/home/user/catkin_ws/src/clfsm/src/clfsm_visitors.cc
-rw-rw-r--|user|user|/home/user/catkin_ws/src/clfsm/src/clfsm_main.cc
-rw-rw-r--|user|user|/home/user/catkin_ws/src/clfsm/src/clfsm_cc.cc
-rw-rw-r--|user|user|/home/user/catkin_ws/src/clfsm/cmake/FindLibDispatch.cmake
-rw-rw-r--|user|user|/home/user/catkin_ws/src/clfsm/CMakeLists.txt
-rw-rw-r--|user|user|/home/user/catkin_ws/src/clfsm/include/clfsm_vector_factory.h
drwxrwxr-x|user|user|/home/user/catkin_ws/src/clfsm/include/typeClassDefs
-rw-rw-r--|user|user|/home/user/catkin_ws/src/clfsm/include/typeClassDefs/FSMControlStatus.h
-rw-rw-r--|user|user|/home/user/catkin_ws/src/clfsm/include/typeClassDefs/FSM_Control.h
-rw-rw-r--|user|user|/home/user/catkin_ws/src/clfsm/include/typeClassDefs/wb_fsm_control_status.h
-rw-rw-r--|user|user|/home/user/catkin_ws/src/clfsm/include/typeClassDefs/wb_fsm_state_status.h
-rw-rw-r--|user|user|/home/user/catkin_ws/src/clfsm/include/CLActionAction.h
-rw-rw-r--|user|user|/home/user/catkin_ws/src/clfsm/include/FSMWBQueryPredicate.h
-rw-rw-r--|user|user|/home/user/catkin_ws/src/clfsm/include/FSMSuspensibleMachine.h
-rw-rw-r--|user|user|/home/user/catkin_ws/src/clfsm/include/FSMWBSubMachine.h
-rw-rw-r--|user|user|/home/user/catkin_ws/src/clfsm/include/gu_util.h~
-rw-rw-r--|user|user|/home/user/catkin_ws/src/clfsm/include/CLTransitionExpression.h
-rw-rw-r--|user|user|/home/user/catkin_ws/src/clfsm/include/FSMWBContext.h
-rw-rw-r--|user|user|/home/user/catkin_ws/src/clfsm/include/FSMState.h
-rw-rw-r--|user|user|/home/user/catkin_ws/src/clfsm/include/FSMAction.h
-rw-rw-r--|user|user|/home/user/catkin_ws/src/clfsm/include/FSMExpression.h
-rw-rw-r--|user|user|/home/user/catkin_ws/src/clfsm/include/clfsm_cc.h
-rw-rw-r--|user|user|/home/user/catkin_ws/src/clfsm/include/FSMTransition.h
-rw-rw-r--|user|user|/home/user/catkin_ws/src/clfsm/include/clfsm_visitorsupport.h
-rw-rw-r--|user|user|/home/user/catkin_ws/src/clfsm/include/stringConstants.h
-rw-rw-r--|user|user|/home/user/catkin_ws/src/clfsm/include/clfsm_factory.h
-rw-rw-r--|user|user|/home/user/catkin_ws/src/clfsm/include/FSMFactory.h
-rw-rw-r--|user|user|/home/user/catkin_ws/src/clfsm/include/FSMachineVector.h
-rw-rw-r--|user|user|/home/user/catkin_ws/src/clfsm/include/FSMActivity.h
-rw-rw-r--|user|user|/home/user/catkin_ws/src/clfsm/include/clfsm_visitors.h
-rw-rw-r--|user|user|/home/user/catkin_ws/src/clfsm/include/FSMachine.h
-rw-rw-r--|user|user|/home/user/catkin_ws/src/clfsm/include/clfsm_cc_delegate.h
-rw-rw-r--|user|user|/home/user/catkin_ws/src/clfsm/include/clfsm_machine.h
-rw-rw-r--|user|user|/home/user/catkin_ws/src/clfsm/include/gu_util.h
-rw-rw-r--|user|user|/home/user/catkin_ws/src/clfsm/include/FSMWBPredicate.h
-rw-rw-r--|user|user|/home/user/catkin_ws/src/clfsm/include/clfsm_wb_vector_factory.h
-rw-rw-r--|user|user|/home/user/catkin_ws/src/clfsm/include/FSM.h
-rw-rw-r--|user|user|/home/user/catkin_ws/src/clfsm/package.xml
-rw-rw-r--|user|user|/home/user/catkin_ws/src/clfsm/clfsm.cbp

user@rMBP-Ubuntu:[12:34]:/home/user/catkin_ws/src/clfsm$ find /home/user/catkin_ws/src/clfsm  \( ! -path /home/user/catkin_ws/src/clfsm/cmake ! -path '/home/user/catkin_ws/src/clfsm/cmake/*' ! -path /home/user/catkin_ws/src/clfsm/include ! -path '/home/user/catkin_ws/src/clfsm/include/*' \) -ls | awk '{print $3"|"$5"|"$6"|"$11}'
drwxrwxr-x|user|user|/home/user/catkin_ws/src/clfsm
-rw-rw-r--|user|user|/home/user/catkin_ws/src/clfsm/clfsm.layout
drwxrwxr-x|user|user|/home/user/catkin_ws/src/clfsm/src
-rw-rw-r--|user|user|/home/user/catkin_ws/src/clfsm/src/clfsm_visitorsupport.cc
-rw-rw-r--|user|user|/home/user/catkin_ws/src/clfsm/src/clfsm_machine.cc
-rw-rw-r--|user|user|/home/user/catkin_ws/src/clfsm/src/clfsm_visitors.cc
-rw-rw-r--|user|user|/home/user/catkin_ws/src/clfsm/src/clfsm_main.cc
-rw-rw-r--|user|user|/home/user/catkin_ws/src/clfsm/src/clfsm_cc.cc
-rw-rw-r--|user|user|/home/user/catkin_ws/src/clfsm/CMakeLists.txt
-rw-rw-r--|user|user|/home/user/catkin_ws/src/clfsm/package.xml
-rw-rw-r--|user|user|/home/user/catkin_ws/src/clfsm/clfsm.cbp
user@rMBP-Ubuntu:[12:35]:/home/user/catkin_ws/src/clfsm$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the requirement properly you should be using `-path ... -prune` to stop descending into trees.

Something like:

```
#!/bin/bash -f
# output permissions and ownership with path relative to specified parent.

Usage="$0 <parent path> <excluded child folder> ...."

if [ $# -lt 1 ]
then
    (>&2 echo -e $Usage)
    exit 1
else 
    parent=$1
    shift
    if [ $# -gt 0 ]
    then
        for folder in $@
        do
            thisLine=" ( -path $parent/$folder -prune ) -o"
            excludes=$excludes$thisLine
        done
    fi
set -vx
    find $parent $excludes -ls | awk '{print $3"|"$5"|"$6"|"$11}'
fi
```

The idea is to build out a string similar to

```
find /tmp/A \( -path /tmp/A/skip1 -prune \) -o -ls
```

Comment: Thnx for that.  However, the `-prune isn't doing what I'm looking for.  You'll notice that I'm echoing the command before the 'equivalent' gets executed.  If you copy/paste it, and escape the leading/trailing parenthesis, you will see the output is different to what your script gives.

Comment: Please provide an example of the tree and the output you're expecting.  Your example code doesn't seem to match the written requirements, so I'm obviously not understanding your problem properly.

Comment: I have added the use case explanation to my OP.  Also, what does the `-o` option do?  I found it, but shouldn't it have a parameter 0-3.

Comment: So that's the bit I don't understand.  You added `cmake` as an "exclude" but I can see `cmake` lines in the output.  So how is that excluded?  That's what I tried to fix.  But maybe I misunderstood the question.  And I'm not sure I still do!  If you're just worried about the lack of a / then change `$parent/$folder` to `$parent$folder` and you'll need it again.  `-o` is "or".  The command built is `find ... \( -path ext1 -prune \) -o \( -path ext2 -prune \) -o -ls`

Comment: Scroll down to the second part of the output.

Comment: And how does my version of the script compare?

Comment: The alteration you made has fixed it up.  Cheers!!  Without the globbing `*`, it's much easier.  I would still like to understand how to escape the `*` in this example using my code template for future developments.

Comment: In this case you might have wanted to simply cheat; `set -o noglob` to stop the shell trying to expand the `*` wildcard

Comment: I actually had already done that, in the shebang.